# Galois field of order $p^n$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

Can someone help me in establishing an image of how the group looks like. I am having a hard time visualizing it.

Comment: Just as finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ are basically $\mathbb{Q}^n$ with defined multiplications (corresponding to the minimal polynomial the generator satisfies), $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ is basically $\mathbb{F}_p^n$ with defined multiplications.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/591254/11619) the elements of $GF(4)$, $GF(8)$ and $GF(16)$ are listed together with examples of arithmetic operations in those fields. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

See [Galois' Theorem and Polynomial Arithmetic](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~mrh/330tutor/ch04s02.html).